# How to make a wordpress site multilingual by uploading a translated CSV file that has the traslations?

Tags: multi-language, csv

I have a website which is in french and i need the website to be read by my users in english too. How do i achieve that without making or creating entirely new pages with english translations. I have a CSV file which contains text which have french to english translation for each word.

Comment: Creating new pages would be the cleanest solution as they can then be indexed by Google etc. Another way would be to use Custom Post Fields to store your translation and then output those below the article text once you click on a button. Or even replace the article text with the content from the CPF by using jQuery or alike. Lots of ways to go, but CSV won't help you in WordPress.

Comment: Personally I like the [qTranslate-X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) approach. It stores the translations in the same post fields, with codes separating the languages, so no post duplication. For example, the title would be **[:fr]Titre en français[:en]Title in English[:]**, so you could export all of your posts and combine them in a CSV to reimport them.

Comment: @flomei I tried editing the .po and .mo files of the theme and translated the theme's text successfully. But now stuck on the point as to how to achieve the same for the various post and pages content that i have.

Comment: @PeterHvD How do i export my posts without the html tags and after translation how do i add those tags again to the translated content.

Comment: You would need a plugin that exports and imports posts to CSV format. Have a search in the repository - there are quite a few!

Comment: @PeterHvD But then again the problem would be the plugin will export the content with HTML tags and i need to remove those tags and then again add the tags to their respective places.